# Can not get msconfig .exe to run in the system32 folder shellexecute Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, system32

Im on Win 7  64b.
Im trying to run msconfig from my delphi app.
The msconfig.exe file is in the system32 folder .
I copied the msconfig.exe to the c:\ and it works great.
This looks like some kind of permission issue.

```
var
errorcode: integer;
 begin
   errorcode :=
ShellExecute(0, 'open', pchar('C:\Windows\System\msconfig.exe'), nil, nil, SW_NORMAL);
if errorcode <= 32 then
ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(errorcode));
end;
```

Has anyone seen this and figured out how to run the msconfig.exe from the sys32 .

Comment: What is the error message you see?

Comment: *The system cannot find the file specified* ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behavior is caused by the [`File System Redirector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as workaround you can use the [`Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365744%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}


uses
  ShellAPi,
  SysUtils;

Function Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(Var Wow64FsEnableRedirection: LongBool): LongBool; StdCall;
  External 'Kernel32.dll' Name 'Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection';
Function Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection(Wow64FsEnableRedirection: LongBool): LongBool; StdCall;
  External 'Kernel32.dll' Name 'Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection';


Var
  Wow64FsEnableRedirection: LongBool;

begin
  try
   Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(Wow64FsEnableRedirection);
   ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar('C:\Windows\System32\msconfig.exe'), nil, nil, 0);
   Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection(Wow64FsEnableRedirection);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: This is a process-wide setting. If you have running threads in the background that aren't expecting things like this to change, they could be adversely affected.

Never mind :-). The documentation says it is thread centric not process centric.

Comment: Instead of disabling FS redirection, you should instead use the special ”SysNative" alias instead of the ”System32" folder directly when running under WOW64 on a 64-bit system: `PChar('C:\Windows\SysNative\msconfig.exe')`. Use `IsWow64Process()` to detect WOW64.

Comment: Disabling file system redirection is very risky. Please please do not do it. Instead do exactly what Remy said.

Answer (score 3):

To access the 64-bit System folder from a 32-bit process, you should use the special ”SysNative" alias instead of the ”System32" folder directly:

```
PChar('C:\Windows\SysNative\msconfig.exe')
```

If you need to support 32-bit OS versions or 64-bit compiling, use `IsWow64Process()` to detect if your app is running under WOW64:

```
{$IFDEF WIN64}
function IsWow64: Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
end;
{$ELSE}
function IsWow64Process(hProcess: THandle; out Wow64Process: BOOL): BOOL; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll' delayed;

function IsWow64: Boolean;
var
  Ret: BOOL;
begin
  Result := False;
  // XP = v5.1
  if (Win32MajorVersion > 5) or
    ((Win32MajorVersion = 5) and (Win32MinorVersion >= 1)) then
  begin
    if IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), Ret) then
      Result := Ret <> 0;
  end;
end;
{$ENDIF}

var
  errorcode: integer;
  SysFolder: string;
begin
  If IsWow64 then
    SysFolder := 'SysNative'
  else
    SysFolder := 'System32';
  errorcode := ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar('C:\Windows\'+SysFolder'+\msconfig.exe'), nil, nil, SW_NORMAL);
  if errorcode <= 32 then
    ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(errorcode));
end;
```

Comment: +1 this is how to do it. For what it's worth you may as well test for ver >= 5.2 because 5.1 is 32 bit only. XP64 was 5.2. It was built off server 2003 code base.

Comment: +1 too, just `nil` will be better operation for `ShellExecute`.

Comment: In case anyone tries this out, I found that you need to call `ShellExecute` from an elevated process in order for msconfig to start. But when running a 64 bit process, that was not required. Mysterious.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the calling process does not need to be elevated. msconfig has its own UAC elevation manifest that specifies `requestedExecutionLevel=requireAdministrator`, at least on Win7, so it should get elevated automatically when started. But if your version of msconfig does not have that manifest, you can specify the `"runas"` verb instead of the `"open"` verb when calling `ShellExecute()`, and it will still prompt the user for elevation when starting the msconfig.exe process.

Comment: That's what I thought. I already tried that before I commented. On my system msconfig fails to start from a wow64 process, path specified in sysnative, unless that wow64 process is elevated. Don't understand.

Comment: thanks for answer. Is there other way to run 64bit explorer.exe from 32 bit app?

Comment: @mca64: Just run `explorer.exe` from the root Windows folder, it will launch the 64bit version. If explorer is already running, it will take over the call and simply open a new window.  If you don't want that, you can specify the `/separate` parameter to force a new process, but it will still be 64bit.

Answer (score 2):

If you're building a 32bit Delphi app, then when it runs on 64bit Windows, the System32 folder is actually remapped. To a 32bit application, System32 is actually SysWOW64. Because you "see" it in System32 from the Explorer or cmd.exe, is because those are 64bit processes.
In this case, a 32bit process cannot "see" the actual 64bit System32 folder.

One solution is to get the latest Delphi which supports 64bit targeting and build a 64bit version.